# import the Win7.vdi in virtualbox after I reinstall Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox

I reinstalled Ubuntu and want to recover the Win7 I installed in virtualbox on the previous Ubuntu. I have a Win7.vdi copied from the `/home/VirtualBox VMs/Win7` folder. Is it possible to do that?

I followed the steps from https://blogs.oracle.com/oswald/importing-a-vdi-in-virtualbox. But it seems them have more than one vdi files.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to do that?

Yes. After installing vbox you navigate to the container and select it.

> /home/VirtualBox VMs/Win7

/home/ should be for USERS only. Please store those containers in your user directory in /home/

===

> But the win7 can't start (I mean, stuck in the middle of booting).

That could be a setting in virtual box. Like too low video memory.

Comment: In Vbox, I use `create new` and then select my Win7.vdi in the hard disk step `using an existing virtual hard disk file`. And the setup seems done after that. But the win7 can't start (I mean, stuck in the middle of booting). It was fine on the previous Ubuntu. Do I need to configure something? Or maybe I used a different version of Vbox?

Comment: Does it get stuck in the middle of Win 7 Boot or does it get stuck during the VirtualBox start up (before win 7 starts booting) ?

Different Version shouldn't make difference unless you went down a version not up.

Comment: In the middle of Win 7 boot. At the stage of black background with "Starting Windows". I am now using the same version of Vbox.

Comment: I used exactly the same setting (all default). So does it mean that I have to reinstall the Win 7 in Vbox?

Comment: I'm guessing you don't have access to the original image anymore ? It looks like the issue with the windows it self rather than vbox as I have previously moved my virtual machines around on USB sticks. Might be corrupted image. Try pressing F8 during boot to see if you can recover it in safe mode.

Comment: It stoped at `windows\system32\drivers\disk.sys`. Any idea?

Comment: That means the image is corrupted unfortunately. I have the same thing with a disk I am trying to clone to a new HDD the problem (or similar one) appears after I try to resize the partition. Unfortunately I have no found a way around it yet and I don't think there is. You can try making recovery USB and try to fix the disk from there but this is definitely a problem with your windows not Ubuntu or Virtualdisk

Comment: @ZhujieGu Please [edit] your question to reflect all the details you posted in the comments. It helps to keep our Q&A style tidy and could also bring more attention since an edited question gets bounced on the homepage. See also [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756/217657)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is normally possible to Import disk image from another computer by simply copying it and selecting it in VirtualBox.

Your problem unfortunately is with the disk image it self and the installation of Windows.

Try running Recovery as per this page 
[Disk Recovery Windows](https://support.hp.com/gb-en/document/c02058933)

Other than this you can also if you have access to the old image try to create a snapshot of the image and copy this one across in hopes to recover it, if you can do that I would also suggest running this command in command prompt with admin rights

```
sfc /scannow
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please review https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer Thank you!